# Proving least upper bounds within the set of real numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

If A is a subset of B and A,B are non-empty sets that are subsets of the set of Real Numbers R, and if B has a least upper bound, then how can I prove that A has a least upper bound and that the lub A is less than or equal to lub B

Comment: What you want to show is that if $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $B$, it must also be an upper bound of $A$.  Really, the whole answer comes down to shuffling definitions

Answer (score 0):

First suppose that $A $ has no least upper bound to arrive at a contradiction, proving it has. Then suppose its least upper bound is greater than $B $'s to arrive at another contraction, showing it isn't greater *i.e.* it is less than or equal to $B $ least upper bound.

Comment: Let me see if I am following this correctly,

Comment: Let me see if I am following this correctly, if "a" is a lub for B, then "a" is also a lub for A because A is a subset of B. Since A is a subset of B, then the lub A must be less than or equal to lub B. I think I am understanding this, and I will continue to work to prove the statement through contradiction.

Comment: @user145551 those are exactly the right claims. A rigorous proof for them should only take manipulation of definitions.

Comment: I'll continue to work on it, thank you.